# Sort a list of tuples by their first index in Elm

Tags: list, sorting, comparison, elm

Assuming that I have a list of tuples that resemble the following example:

```
[(5, "a"), (1, "c"), (7, "d")]
```

in Elm, how do I go about sorting the list in ascending order by their first elements so that we get the following result?

```
[(1, "c"), (5, "a"), (7, "d")]
```

Using the [Elm List documentation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/List), it appears that the [`sortBy`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/List#sortBy) and [`sortWith`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/List#sortWith) functions will be useful for this case. My attempt at an implementation is as follows:

```
maxTuples : Tuple(a, b) -> Tuple(a, b) -> Tuple(a, b)
maxTuples t1 t2 = 
    case compare t1 t2 of 
        ((Tuple.first t1) >= (Tuple.first t2)) -> GT
         _                                     -> LT


sortByFirst : List (Tuple (a, b)) -> List (Tuple (a, b))
sortByFirst lst = 
    List.sortWith maxTuples lst
```

However, I'm getting compiler errors of the following nature:

```
I ran into something unexpected when parsing your code!

99|         ((Tuple.first t1) >= (Tuple.first t2)) -> GT
                ^
I am looking for one of the following things:

an upper case name
```

My hunch would be that the compiler is looking for `GT`/`LT`/`EQ` per the API of `List` library, but if this the case I'm not sure how we would be able to use either `sortBy` or `sortWith` to sort a list of Tuples in Elm by the first index of each element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You found the right functions. In your code, there are actually multiple problems:

1. The type annotations should be just `(a, b)`, not `Tuple(a, b)`.
2. You compare `t1` with `t2`, which will compare the tuples lexicographically. You actually want `compare (Tuple.first t1) (Tuple.first t2)`
3. The [`case`](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#conditionals) branches require a pattern before the `->`. In this case would be something like `EQ`, since you are matching on the result of [`compare`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Basics#compare), which returns [`Order`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Basics#Order) type.

You could fix the code like this:

```
maxTuples : (comparable, b) -> (comparable, b) -> (comparable, b)
maxTuples t1 t2 = 
    case compare (Tuple.first t1) (Tuple.first t2) of 
        GT -> GT
        EQ -> EQ
         _ -> LT
```

But now there is an unnecessary repetition, you are simply returning the result of `compare` function.

```
maxTuples t1 t2 = 
    compare (Tuple.first t1) (Tuple.first t2)
```

Together with the sort function, it would look like this:

```
sortByFirst lst = 
    List.sortWith (\t1 t2 -> compare (Tuple.first t1) (Tuple.first t2)) lst
```

It turns out this kind of operation is quite common, especially with lists of records. For this reason, Elm offers another function – [`sortBy`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/List#sortBy). It takes a function and compares the elements after applying the function:

```
sortBy f lst =
    List.sortWith (\a b -> compare (f a) (f b)) lst
```

You can therefore use `sortBy` function to greatly simplify the code:

```
sortByFirst : List (comparable, b) -> List (comparable, b)
sortByFirst =
    sortBy Tuple.first
```

Comment: The compiler indicates that the signatures should be 

    List (comparable, a2) -> List (comparable, a2) 

but this is the right idea.

Comment: @AdamFreymiller Yes, that is more precise. I will edit it into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is worth noting that what you want is the default behavior of `List.sort` (sort will use the first element of the tuple to order the list and if two elements have the same first element will move to compare the second and so on)

`List.sort [(5, "a"), (1, "c"), (1, "a"), (7, "d")] == [(1,"a"),(1,"c"),(5,"a"),(7,"d")]`

Using sortBy in this case is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `compare` is in `case compare t1 t2 of`, but you can just use a straight `if` instead of a `case` (and also use destructuring instead of `Tuple.first`, if you prefer):

```
maxTuples ( val1, _ ) ( val2, _ ) =
    if val1 >= val2 then
        GT
    else
        LT
```

I have a complete working example at https://ellie-app.com/ZZ9Hzhg7yva1/2 (there were also some type annotation changes that needed to be made to get it compiling)

However, `sortBy` is the simpler option, because it can just take `Tuple.first` to sort by whatever is in there:

```
sortByFirst lst =
    List.sortBy Tuple.first lst
```

That version is at https://ellie-app.com/ZZ9Hzhg7yva1/3